# MySQL Solving data load problems?

Tags: mysql

I have experienced several problems trying to load data from a text or a csv file, into a table in a `MySQL Workbench database`.

First of all, the system was unable to find the text file with the path `c:\test.txt`.

From Stackoverflow I learned that when using Windows, either a slash, `/`, og two double backslashes ,`\\`, should be used instead. In some cases you can use `/`, in other cases you can´t.

Does anyone know why?

As soon as this was solved, my other problem appeared to be occurring when trying to load data into a table, from a file.

First of all, I created a table using this script:

```
CREATE TABLE testtable (
    entry_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    title VARCHAR(80),
    book_number INT
);
```

Then I made a text file, `test.txt`, with these contents :

```
1,first book,17
2,second book,34
3,third book,64
4,fourth book,69
```

and placed it on the `c-drive`.

Finally I tried to load the data from the text file into the table '`testtable`', using this script:

> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:\test.txt' INTO TABLE testtable;

The following error messages appeared :

```
18:10:05    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:\\test.txt' INTO TABLE testtable  4 row(s) affected, 12 warning(s): 1265 Data truncated for column 'entry_id' at row 1 1261 Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns 1261 Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns 1265 Data truncated for column 'entry_id' at row 2 1261 Row 2 doesn't contain data for all columns 1261 Row 2 doesn't contain data for all columns 1265 Data truncated for column 'entry_id' at row 3 1261 Row 3 doesn't contain data for all columns 1261 Row 3 doesn't contain data for all columns 1265 Data truncated for column 'entry_id' at row 4 1261 Row 4 doesn't contain data for all columns 1261 Row 4 doesn't contain data for all columns Records: 4  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 12  0.031 sec
```

I have tried both txt and csv files, and in some cases have received error messages about incorrect integer values.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first column is autogenerated, as it is primary key and autoincrement. Try not to put the first integer in the csv file, just put two columns per row on the file.

Answer (score 0):

First I would like to thank Diego for his answer.

Since I asked the questions about loading data into tables in a MySQL database, I have found reasons for at least some of the problems. I would like to share this with the **stack**overflow participants.

It is fairly easy to load data from a text file into a table in a MySQL database. There are, however, several issues that should be considered, before attempting this, and there are several sources to errors which may occur. The difficult part is to find out what causes any specific problem.

When creating a text file for later load into a MySQL database table, the first thing to be considered is how to arrange data. In my experience, the only way that works is to arrange data values in rows with one single record in each line, and to separate the values by tabs. Do not separate values by commas.

When this is done, you can save your text file using the extensions .txt or .csv.

Another problem that turned out to be a specific one for me, was caused by saving some of the text files using a unicode character encoding. Apparently, MySQL does not recognize neither the unicode nor the UTF-8 encoding, which leaves the ANSI encoding, the only option available. Unicode offers the option of saving non-English letters and characters, which is why I have used it in certain cases.

The problem I mentioned about incorrect integer values, was caused by text files saved in unicode.

I still haven´t found out about when it is possible to point to a file path using a single backslash, and when to use double backslash or a single slash, following the drive letter.

I welcome comments.

Thank you.

Comment: MySQL supports many encodings including UTF-8 and unicode. As for importing data in CSV, unicode is not supported but UTF-8 is. Separating your values with either commas or semi-colons works just fine, have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html and the syntax therein. As for file paths on Windows, have you tried wrapping with double quotes (I'm no Windows expert but I've usually seen double quotes in command line arguments).